Is there a way in Google Earth Engine to compute zonal stats for pixels falling to a certain extent (e.g at least 70%) into the desired area?
I have a shapefile containing fifteen circular polygons of 80 m radius. The polygons are spread all cross Europe, from Italy to France, Germany, Belgium, and Sweden.
My task is to compute the average, min, max, median and some percentiles for several Vegetation indices derived from Sentinel-2 imagery.
For each site, I’m interested in 4-5 different dates; dates differ across sites. All dates fall somewhere between 2020 and 2024.
Here is my perplexity: I would like to only include, for the zonal stats' computation, only pixels that fall for at least 70 % of their surface into my polygons.
I tried to better explain the situation in figure A and B.

I am fairly sure that weighted/unweighted reducers would not do the trick; plus, I don't thnik it would make any sense since we are talking about vegetation indices.
As far as i know, ee.Image.reduceRegion has no argument  for controlling such an aspect.
At the moment, I've worked using only 1 site. I'm working in Java. The following steps have already been successfully completed:

Import of the shapefile and the S2 Level 2A feature collection.

filter of the collection for the study period and by bounds.

computation of some of the vegetation indices of interest. Indices have been stored into a variable called soloIndices.

Computation of the desired values for each index (mean, min, max and different percentiles).


The code I've written seems to work, however I cannot understand how (and where) i might control the parameter i'm interested in (only including pixels falling for at least 70 % into the polygon for the computation of the zonal stats).

// 1) import the vector of the area;
// 2) import the S2 collection
// 3) filter the collection by date and extent
// 4) write a function to calculate the spectral indices for each image of the collection and add the index in a new file
// 5) calculate the stats for each polygon 
// 6) export in a table

// 1) import the vector of the area;

var cp2 = ee.FeatureCollection('projects/ee-sebastianilsn3/assets/CP2');// area imported
var cp2g = cp2.geometry();// area converted to geometry

// 2) import the S2 collection  3) filter the collection by date and extent
var filtered = s2.filter(ee.Filter.lt('CLOUDY_PIXEL_PERCENTAGE', 30))
  .filter(ee.Filter.date('2020-01-01', '2023-12-01'))
  .filter(ee.Filter.bounds(cp2g)); //collection imported and filtered

//4) write a function to calculate the spectral indices for each image of the collection and add the index in a new file

function addIndices(image) {
  var ndvi = image.normalizedDifference(['B8', 'B4']).rename('ndvi');
  var ndwi = image.normalizedDifference(['B3', 'B8']).rename('ndwi');
  var savi = image.expression(
    '1.5 * ((NIR - RED) / (NIR + RED + 0.5))', {
      'NIR': image.select('B8'),
      'RED': image.select('B4'),
}).rename('savi');
 var reip = image.expression(
    '700 + 40 * ((R + RE7)/2 - RE5) / (RE6 - RE5)', {
      'R': image.select('B4'),
      'RE7': image.select('B7'),
      'RE5': image.select('B5'),
      'RE6': image.select('B6'),
}).rename('reip');
  return image.addBands(ndvi).addBands(ndwi).addBands(savi).addBands(reip);
}

var withIndices = filtered.map(addIndices); // map the function over the filtered collection

var soloIndices =withIndices.select('ndvi', 'ndwi','savi','reip'); // creating a new item containing only the VIs


var soloNdvi = withIndices.select('ndvi');
//print(soloNdvi, 'solo NDVI');

var soloNdwi = withIndices.select('ndwi');
//print(soloNdwi, 'solo NDWI');

var composite = withIndices.median();
var ndviComp = composite.select('ndvi'); // this way I get the ndvi!

// here i add the map of NDVI
var palette = [
  'FFFFFF', 'CE7E45', 'DF923D', 'F1B555', 'FCD163', '99B718',
  '74A901', '66A000', '529400', '3E8601', '207401', '056201',
  '004C00', '023B01', '012E01', '011D01', '011301'];
var ndviVis = {min: 0.3, max: 0.8, bands: ['ndvi'], palette: palette};


// this is the function to extract the desired statistics from the Vegetation indices
var valueComp = function(image){
  var reduct = image.reduceRegion({
    reducer: ee.Reducer.mean().unweighted().combine({reducer2: ee.Reducer.min(), sharedInputs: true} )
  .combine({reducer2: ee.Reducer.max(), sharedInputs: true} )
  .combine({reducer2: ee.Reducer.percentile([25]), sharedInputs: true} )
  .combine({reducer2: ee.Reducer.percentile([50]), sharedInputs: true} )
  .combine({reducer2: ee.Reducer.percentile([75]), sharedInputs: true} ),
    geometry: cp2,
    scale: 10,
    maxPixels: 1e10
  });
  // Extract the properties from the dictionary and then form the list
  reduct = ee.List(ee.Dictionary(reduct));

  // Put the results into a Feature without geometry
  return ee.Feature(null, reduct); // che cosa è reduct? una list?
}; // function is complete

// 5) calculate the stats for each polygon 
var result = soloIndices.map(valueComp); // here I map the function over the collection

print(result); 

// 6) export in a table
Export.table.toDrive({
  collection: result,
  folder: 'GEE TESTS',
  description:'VEG_IND_S2',
  fileFormat: 'CSV'
}); // here I export the table



are you sure that is related to the Java Programming Language, as described for the [tag:java] tag? Or just another case of http://javascriptisnotjava.com/ ...
